# Почему не работает float?

Tags: html, css

Почему в данном примере у `b-navbar__search` не работает float?

```css
.b-navbar__search {
  float: right;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.b-navbar__nav-cell {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.left {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="l-header__row l-header__nav grid-container">
  <div class="b-navbar clearfix">
    <div class="b-navbar__nav-cell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores eveniet doloribus magnam rem. Dolores nihil nisi ad nostrum quod amet, temporibus voluptatum magnam optio dicta maiores doloribus? Quia, magnam! Odio?
    </div>
    <div class="b-navbar__search">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi totam est nostrum perspiciatis facere. Ea doloremque, tenetur dolorem inventore eum recusandae fugit nulla placeat dolorum explicabo dicta blanditiis reiciendis consequatur.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не совсем понимаете принцип отображения блочных элементов. По умолчанию, они занимают всю ширину экрана, и "обтекание" будет происходить, только если ширина у элементов позволяет им "обтекать" друг друга.

Comment: @Klimenkomud, так в первом блоке вроде никаких ограничений нет, но флоат не работает.

Comment: А ограничения должны быть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы поставили `b-navbar__search` после текста(+ div с контентом получает ширину 100%). При таком раскладе вам надо установить ширину для текста и установить `float:right;`

```css
.b-navbar__search {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.b-navbar__nav-cell {
width:85%;
float:right;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="l-header__row l-header__nav grid-container">
  <div class="b-navbar clearfix">
    <div class="b-navbar__nav-cell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores eveniet doloribus magnam rem. Dolores nihil nisi ad nostrum quod amet, temporibus voluptatum magnam optio dicta maiores doloribus? Quia, magnam! Odio?
    </div>
    <div class="b-navbar__search">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Наконецто понял что имелось ввиду. Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ, что обтекание работает только для елементов которые находятся после float. А то я этот нюанс упустил и не сразу вас понял.